# add new property in Typescript object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to add new property in object, but typescript given error.

> error TS2339: Property 'qty' does not exist on type 'Object'.

```
product: Object = {qty: Number};

foo(){
  this.product.qty = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Object` is the wrong annotation. Change your annotation:

```
product: {qty: number} = {qty: 0};

foo(){
  this.product.qty = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> `Number` is a data type not a value. the object only accept the value not datatype. So you can't declare number as a value

try this simple way

```
product: any;

foo(){
  this.product.qty = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you've tried to do this:

```
product: {qty: number} = {};

foo(){
  this.product.qty = 1;
}
```

This won't work, although, because the object you've started with is incomplete. You should either mark the property as optional:

```
product: {qty?: number} = {};

foo(){
  this.product.qty = 1;
}
```

Or provide some default value:

```
product: {qty: number | null} = {qty: null};
// or just {qty: number}, if you don't use strict null checks

foo(){
  this.product.qty = 1;
}
```

If default value is a number too, you can even simplify this by using type inference:

```
product = {qty: 0};

foo(){
  this.product.qty = 1;
}
```

All these three examples will work (if you provide proper value for `this` in function `foo`, of course, but I assume that you'll do it anyway).

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
product = {qty: null};
```

OR

```
product = {qty: 0};
```

instead of this -

```
product: Object = {qty: Number};
```

Because you initializing your object with key and value as `type` which is `number` so instead of assigning type you need to set some value which is anything say `0` or `null` or anything you want as the default value.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do like this and add as many as new properties you want in a product

```
product: Object = new Object();

foo(){
  this.product['qty'] = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution without extra code would be a config option to allow the creation of new properties with the assignment operator but since there is no such property i patched the typescript code to allow it.

Do this on both tsc.js and typescript.js, those files are in node_modules/typescript

Find this line

```
 if (right.escapedText && !checkAndReportErrorForExtendingInterface(node))
```

And paste this right under it

```
return getTypeOfSymbol(right);
```

I have to admit that im not a typescript src code developer and i havent tested extensively the side effects of doing this but it works for my projects

The linter will show an error but it will compile fine

Answer (score -1):

Change Object to any type

```
product: any = {qty: Number};

foo(){
  this.product.qty = 1;
}
```

Comment: Using any defeats the purpose of using TypeScript, especially on the context of OPs question.