# How do you to implement a GRPC server in TypeScript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, protocol-buffers, grpc

I am trying to use @grpc/proto-loader to do dynamic code generation of the protobuf files to implement a simple server but in Typescript.

I've gotten as far as

```js
import { Server, loadPackageDefinition, ServerCredentials } from "grpc";
import { loadSync } from "@grpc/proto-loader";

const packageDefinition = loadSync(__dirname + "/protos/ArtifactUpload.proto");
const protoDescriptor = loadPackageDefinition(packageDefinition);
const impl = {
};
const server = new Server();
server.addService(protoDescriptor.ArtifactUpload, impl);
server.bind('0.0.0.0:50051', ServerCredentials.createInsecure());
server.start();
```

So I have two problems

1. in the [Javascript examples](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/examples/node/dynamic_codegen/greeter_server.js) they use `protoDescriptor.XXX.service` however, there's no `service` property in `protoDescriptor.ArtifactUpload`
2. if I try to add implementation methods in `impl`, the compiler also fails to compile.

Since the Javascript example works, I am thinking that questions along the line of [add new property in Typescript object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51055405/add-new-property-in-typescript-object) may be able to add the necessary service type.  However, I haven't had luck so far.

My Protobuf is

```proto
syntax = "proto3";

service ArtifactUpload {
   rpc SignedUrlPutObject (UploadRequest) returns (SignedUrlPutObjectResponse) {}
}

message UploadRequest {
  string message = 1;
}

message SignedUrlPutObjectResponse {
  string reply = 1;
}
```

Comment: I have created an example gRPC in node.js typescript, I think you might get some help from it. https://github.com/mirajehossain/nodejs-grpc-example-typescript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working in the end as follows:

In `package.json` I had the following:

```json
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "build": "pbjs -t static-module -w commonjs -o protos.js protos/*.proto && pbts -o protos.d.ts protos.js && tsc",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@grpc/proto-loader": "^0.5.5",
    "google-protobuf": "^3.13.0",
    "grpc": "^1.24.4",
    "typescript": "^4.0.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^14.14.7",
    "protobufjs": "^6.10.1"
  }
}
```

```js
import { Server, loadPackageDefinition, ServerCredentials, GrpcObject, ServiceDefinition, handleUnaryCall } from "grpc";
import { ISignedUrlPutObjectResponse, IUploadRequest, SignedUrlPutObjectResponse } from "./protos";
import { loadSync } from "@grpc/proto-loader";

const packageDefinition = loadSync(__dirname + "/protos/ArtifactUpload.proto");

interface IArtifactUpload {
  signedUrlPutObject: handleUnaryCall<IUploadRequest, ISignedUrlPutObjectResponse>;
}
interface ServerDefinition extends GrpcObject {
  service: any
}
interface ServerPackage extends GrpcObject {
  [name: string]: ServerDefinition
}
const protoDescriptor = loadPackageDefinition(packageDefinition) as ServerPackage;
const server = new Server();
server.addService<IArtifactUpload>(protoDescriptor.ArtifactUpload.service, {
  signedUrlPutObject(call, callback) {
    console.log(call.request.message);
    console.log(callback);
    callback(null, SignedUrlPutObjectResponse.create({ reply: "hello " + call.request.message }));

  }

});
server.bind('0.0.0.0:50051', ServerCredentials.createInsecure());
server.start();
```

I use `protobufjs` to build some of the typings though they are mostly unused as it is not fully compatible with GRPC.  However, it does save time with the request and response typings.

I still needed to create the server typings and apply it to the `protoDescriptor`.  Repeating it here for emphasis.

```js
interface IArtifactUpload {
  signedUrlPutObject(call: ServerUnaryCall<IUploadRequest>, callback: ArtifactUpload.SignedUrlPutObjectCallback): void;
}


interface ServerDefinition extends GrpcObject {
  service: any;
}
interface ServerPackage extends GrpcObject {
  [name: string]: ServerDefinition
}
```

I used `any` for the `service` as it was the only one that allowed me to avoid putting in anything specific to IArtifactUpload Ideally the typing for GrpcObject which at present is

```js
  export interface GrpcObject {
    [name: string]: GrpcObject | typeof Client | ProtobufMessage;
  }
```

should try to provide an object that represents the server.

I linked my solution to https://github.com/protobufjs/protobuf.js/issues/1017#issuecomment-725064230 in case there's a better way that I am missing.

Answer (score 24):

[Updated on 14 May 2021]: TypeScript generation via @grpc/proto-loader is now released with version [0.6.0](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-node/releases/tag/%40grpc%2Fproto-loader%400.6.0)! I've updated my [example here](https://github.com/badsyntax/grpc-js-typescript/tree/master/examples/grpc-proto-loader) to reflect this. You can now install the latest version of proto loader with `npm i @grpc/proto-loader` which will contain the TS generation script. The instructions below are still valid.

---

You can use the proto-loader to generate types.

First, install the proto-loader:

```
npm i @grpc/proto-loader
```

You can then generate the types like so:

```
./node_modules/.bin/proto-loader-gen-types --longs=String --enums=String --defaults --oneofs --grpcLib=@grpc/grpc-js --outDir=proto/ proto/*.proto
```

Here's the proto file I use for this example:

```proto
syntax = "proto3";

package example_package;

message ServerMessage {
  string server_message = 1;
}

message ClientMessage {
  string client_message = 1;
}

service Example {
  rpc unaryCall(ClientMessage) returns (ServerMessage) {}
  rpc serverStreamingCall(ClientMessage) returns (stream ServerMessage) {}
  rpc clientStreamingCall(stream ClientMessage) returns (ServerMessage) {}
  rpc bidirectionalStreamingCall(stream ClientMessage) returns (stream ServerMessage) {}
}
```

Once the types are generated, you can consume them like so:

```
import * as grpc from '@grpc/grpc-js';
import * as protoLoader from '@grpc/proto-loader';
import { ProtoGrpcType } from './proto/example';
import { ClientMessage } from './proto/example_package/ClientMessage';
import { ExampleHandlers } from './proto/example_package/Example';
import { ServerMessage } from './proto/example_package/ServerMessage';

const host = '0.0.0.0:9090';

const exampleServer: ExampleHandlers = {
  unaryCall(
    call: grpc.ServerUnaryCall<ClientMessage, ServerMessage>,
    callback: grpc.sendUnaryData<ServerMessage>
  ) {
    if (call.request) {
      console.log(`(server) Got client message: ${call.request.clientMessage}`);
    }
    callback(null, {
      serverMessage: 'Message from server',
    });
  },

  serverStreamingCall(
    call: grpc.ServerWritableStream<ClientMessage, ServerMessage>
  ) {
    call.write({
      serverMessage: 'Message from server',
    });
  },

  clientStreamingCall(
    call: grpc.ServerReadableStream<ClientMessage, ServerMessage>
  ) {
    call.on('data', (clientMessage: ClientMessage) => {
      console.log(
        `(server) Got client message: ${clientMessage.clientMessage}`
      );
    });
  },

  bidirectionalStreamingCall(
    call: grpc.ServerDuplexStream<ClientMessage, ServerMessage>
  ) {
    call.write({
      serverMessage: 'Message from server',
    });
    call.on('data', (clientMessage: ClientMessage) => {
      console.log(
        `(server) Got client message: ${clientMessage.clientMessage}`
      );
    });
  },
};

function getServer(): grpc.Server {
  const packageDefinition = protoLoader.loadSync('./proto/example.proto');
  const proto = (grpc.loadPackageDefinition(
    packageDefinition
  ) as unknown) as ProtoGrpcType;
  const server = new grpc.Server();
  server.addService(proto.example_package.Example.service, exampleServer);
  return server;
}

if (require.main === module) {
  const server = getServer();
  server.bindAsync(
    host,
    grpc.ServerCredentials.createInsecure(),
    (err: Error | null, port: number) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(`Server error: ${err.message}`);
      } else {
        console.log(`Server bound on port: ${port}`);
        server.start();
      }
    }
  );
}
```

**I've created various examples of how to use gRPC with TypeScript here: https://github.com/badsyntax/grpc-js-typescript**

Comment: Can't thank you enough for the example repos, and for not using @grpc-tools (it doesn't work on M1 macs yet).

Comment: I love you man... Which is to say, thanks for those examples!

Answer (score -1):

Never use @grpc/proto-loader, it uses `eval` under the hood. it is unsecure